# Laravel mix error development how repair?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, laravel-mix, webpack-cli

**Hello now get this all but i have error this: How repair error?**
I run command npm run dev

```
[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/rules/DescriptionDataMatcherRulePlugin'
Require stack:
- C:\xampp\htdocs\project\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\plugin-webpack5.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\project\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\plugin.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\project\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\index.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\project\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\components\Vue.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\project\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\components\ComponentRegistrar.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\project\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\Mix.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\project\node_modules\laravel-mix\setup\webpack.config.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\project\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\project\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\bootstrap.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\project\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\project\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:893:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:743:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\project\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\plugin-webpack5.js:6:42)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1076:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:941:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:782:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\node_modules\\vue-loader\\lib\\plugin-webpack5.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\node_modules\\vue-loader\\lib\\plugin.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\node_modules\\vue-loader\\lib\\index.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\node_modules\\laravel-mix\\src\\components\\Vue.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\node_modules\\laravel-mix\\src\\components\\ComponentRegistrar.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\node_modules\\laravel-mix\\src\\Mix.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\node_modules\\laravel-mix\\setup\\webpack.config.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\lib\\webpack-cli.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\lib\\bootstrap.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\bin\\cli.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\project\\node_modules\\webpack\\bin\\webpack.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! project@1.0.0 development: `mix`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project@1.0.0 development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! project@1.0.0 dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-31T15_48_38_085Z-debug.log
```

Now what this? How repair?
I use command:
npm cache clear
npm install
npm install laravel-mix
npm install --g webpack-cli
npm run dev
and now get error :(

Comment: Ok a found problem is not installed vue-loader.

Comment: U must use command npm i vue-loader

Comment: Now compiled Laravel-Mix. Best Reagards friends.